# Ddos attacks in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I would like to integrate a script that avoid a DDos attack in symfony project. Althought i have tried to create an event listener to do the work, i haven't succeeded.

Below the created script in symfony2 listener:

```
public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {    
    $session = $this->requestStatck->getCurrentRequest()->getSession();

    if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
        // don't do anything if it's not the master request
        return;
    }

    if($session->get('last_session_request') > time() - 2 ){
        die('DDos attack');
    }

    $session->set('last_session_request',  time());
}
```

This one makes me some problems on the page view such as unstyled page, no js,..

I work with the symfony2 version 2.7.7

I look forward to getting solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You're assuming that all the requests will share the session. This is unlikely to happen. Such things should be done on the infrastructure level rather then in the application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have made this script just for a test. The problem is when i set the session parameter " $session->set('last_session_request', time());" the css style doesn't work on page. Whereas, when i remove this line, it works perfectly.

Comment: Do you use assetic? In dev mode its requests go through a controller, so your listener would be called for them as well. As for any ajax request. Again, this is not the right thing to do.

Comment: Could you give me the best solution if you have please !

Comment: As I already mentioned do this on an infrastructure level. Could be done in hundreds of ways - like on firewall, load balancer , web server etc. Example: https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-ddos-attacks-with-nginx-and-nginx-plus/

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception instead of a `die` in your code :

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

// ...

if($session->get('last_session_request') > time() - 2 ){
    throw new HttpException('DDos attack', 403); // Return a 403 Forbidden
}
```

Comment: You should answer your question, I will remove my answer because it's useless.